# Multiple mailboxes with same name in Sidebar

Tags: configuration, email, mutt

I have folder “xxx_mail” on two different IMAP accounts. I want to use Sidebar feature. The problem is there are two “xxx_mail” items. How can I change names shown in the sidebar?

Mailboxes im my `.muttrc`:

```
mailbox imap://foo@imap.example.org/xxx_mail 
mailbox imap://bar@imap.example.org/xxx_mail
```

Answer (score 2):

If you consider switching to `neomutt`, then instead using `mailboxes` command you could use `named-mailboxes`

```
named-mailboxes "description1" mailbox1 "description2" mailbox2
```

and than you can use `%D` (description) in `sidebar-format` string.

Please refer to `named-mailboxes` and `sidebar-format` in `neomuttrc` manpage.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/586351/85046 for more information how to achieve this in mutt.
Since 2020-05-02 Mutt 1.14 it has support for naming `mailboxes` using flag `-label`